# Remove audio file from PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

[image]

Is there a way to delete a custom audio file that I had added from the above list?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select `No Sound` or Any other default sound.
2. Save & Quit and Reopen the file.

Simple as that!

Comment: That was easy enough! Thank you so much!

Comment: Follow up question, is there any way to adjust the volume of the audio present in the list?

Comment: @BhaveshShaha Don't think that's possible from within Powerpoint. If you have purposes like recording or something you can always use the Volume mixer...